# How to add exit icon in tooltip for dissmiss it?

Tags: java, android, tooltip

I have some tooltip for guide user about usage of feature of my apps,
and I wanna close the tooltip after user read all the guide, something like close icon. how to make it brad?
so far I make it with time OverLay how can I add it with closed icon.
this my code

```
Button toolTipShowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tooltip_bottom);
    Tooltip.make(this,
            new Tooltip.Builder(101)
                    .anchor(toolTipShowButton, Tooltip.Gravity.BOTTOM)
                    .closePolicy(new Tooltip.ClosePolicy()
                            .insidePolicy(true, false)
                            .outsidePolicy(true, false), 4000)
                    .activateDelay(900)
                    .showDelay(400)
                    .text("Android PopupWindow with Tooltip Arrow Below Button or view or layout")
                    .maxWidth(600)
                    .withArrow(true)
                    .withOverlay(true).build()
    ).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom  layout and use like this.

```
Tooltip.make(this,
            new Tooltip.Builder(101)
                    .anchor(toolTipShowButton, Tooltip.Gravity.BOTTOM)
                    .closePolicy(new Tooltip.ClosePolicy()
                            .insidePolicy(true, false)
                            .outsidePolicy(true, false), 4000)
                    .activateDelay(900)
                    .showDelay(400)
                    .text("Android PopupWindow with Tooltip Arrow Below Button or view or layout")
                    .maxWidth(600)
                    .withArrow(true)
                    .withCustomView(R.layout.your_view)
                    .withOverlay(true).build()
    ).show();
```

follow this library for more info

```
https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip/blob/master/library/src/main/java/it/sephiroth/android/library/tooltip/Tooltip.java#L1471
```

Comment: thanx,, but I wish you give me something simple adding code from code that I showed above.

Comment: Yeah you can create the layout file and add attribute withCustomView(R.id.Layout). . check my answer properly